# CTRL-TAB in NetBeans not working as it should?

Tags: netbeans

Currently, if I have 4 tabs and I press CTRL TAB, it does not go from 1 to 2, then from 2 to 3 and so on. It jumps between windows in the order I last had them open.

1. Is there a way to switch Zend so that if I press CTRL-TAB it goes from 1 to 2, 2 to 3 and so on.
2. Ideally, will this also allow for CTRL-SHIFT-TAB to go from 4 to 3, then 3 to 2 and so on?

Comment: check this link, might be helpfull:
http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqKeybindings

Comment: I'm under the impression that Ctrl+Tab has always worked like that

Comment: It's always worked like that in Netbeans, but it's not the standard in other apps, like Chrome for example.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Depending on the version of your NetBeans installation, the <kbd>Ctrl+Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Tab</kbd> shortcuts are hardcoded to the PopupSwitcher which appears when pressing <kbd>Ctrl+Tab</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Tab</kbd> a little longer or repeatedly.

The "proper" tab switch you're probably looking for is achieved when pressing <kbd>Ctrl+PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl+PgDown</kbd>. That should switch between tabs in a circular manner.

As for the current version (7.3.1), there seems to be no way to change the key bindings (Tools|Options|Keymap) to <kbd>Ctrl+Tab</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Tab</kbd>, because they are caught by that PopupSwitcher.

The only solution that comes to my mind is to either catch <kbd>Ctrl+Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Tab</kbd> a level before NetBeans (with something like AutoHotkey) and forward <kbd>Ctrl+PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl+PgDown</kbd>. Or you could modify the sources and build NetBeans yourself. See NetBeans sources, module `core.windows`, package `org.netbeans.core.windows.view.ui.popupswitcher`.

Comment: holy crap i think it is still impossible in year 2016